# Wine crashed on playonlinux

Tags: wine, crash, playonlinux

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.I downloaded playonlinux and then prince of persia-the two thrones which started to install wine then wine(gecko) which stopped responding during downloading so I aborted it.Next time when I started downloading it asked me to either create a new virtual drive or abort installation but proceeding further both displayed same error that wine seems to have been crashed.I went throughout the issues related to this but did not find any answer.Please guide me to take further actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlayOnLinux is a "helper application" for [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). Wine is the "translation layer" that allows windows programs to run on linux. However the configuration of wine can be anything from easy to very difficult. This is where PlayOnLinux helps.

PlayOnLinux is two things:

- **a repository of "recepies"** that can automatically download/install/configure windows programs.
- **A Wine-Container-Manager.** This is what they call "virtual drive".

The recepies are there that the normal user does not need to deal with the gory details of wine configuration. The containers (virtual drives) are the killer-feature of this application, because: for each container you can define (and change) the wine version to use.

By default each application is installed into its own container. But you can create a container for each application you install, or you can install all your applications in a single container.

**Install a Program**

Although it says "Install a program" it will only invoke the recepie for the selected program. Some commercial programs will require you to have the original windows- installation media (CD/DVD) ready. Generally it can only do "the complete installation job" if the program is open source. I don't know the status of "The two thrones".

**To address your issue:**

I suggest you delete the container you've created. Then you can start over to install anything you want. To delete the container you do:

- Select "Configure"
- in the new window, in the left pane, click on the container you want to delete
- click the "Remove" button below.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 20.04, PlayOnLinux requires 32-bit wine support, as per their website.
You can install it by typing:

1. Add support for 32-bit if using a 64bit system.

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt update
```

2. Then install wine:

```
sudo apt install wine64 wine32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands to install wine

1. sudo dpkg --add-i386
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install wine:i386

[Reference]

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-13846-Wine_crashes_when_installing_nonlisted_program.html